# What's a good strategy for saving old R package versions on GitHub?

Tags: r, github, devtools

The development of RStudio and the packages `devtools` and `roxygen2` has made R package creation pretty easy. I use GitHub for version control and `devtools` allows others to easily install directly from my account.

As my package gradually changes with each version, I'm wondering if I should be maintaining .zip files (or other format) of my past stable builds, in case anyone would ever want to use a previous version.

It's easy to download a .zip of an R package directly from GitHub, but I'm wondering if I should add this to the same GitHub directory (e.g. https://github.com/myaccount/mypackage/previous_versions/mypackage_0.1.zip) without messing up somebody's installation via `install_github("myaccount/mypackage")`.

So, the main Qs are:

1. Should I keep an old package version at all?
2. Should I keep old package versions in a sub-folder of my GitHub R package directory?
3. Should I save .zip files downloaded from GitHub as my old version, or produce a Source or Binary file during the package build itself (i.e. in RStudio)?
4. Is this a superfluous activity if one isn't yet willing to publish to CRAN?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you think your package is at a good solid place, you should tag a release.  This archives the branch at that point in time and stores the zip file with the source code, and the tar.gz file.

I tend to mark my CRAN packages as a release each time I release it to CRAN (for example, see https://github.com/nutterb/pixiedust/releases) and with some intemediary tags that I consider noteworthy.

Another good strategy for managing changes in between tagged releases is to maintain a development branch below your main branch.  That way your development changes won't pollute or break anything being used by those pulling from your main branch.  It makes you free to experiment in the dev branch while always having a clean, working copy to push to and restore from.

Comment: I like this option - especially since RStudio is not well-adapted to working on branches. Creation of a release also allows for uploading of binaries and source versions of the build. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**1. Should I keep an old package version at all?**

It's subjective, but I'd definitely say "yes" unless there's a space constraint, which is probably unlikely.

This serves 2 purposes. One is for your own convenience, such as if you want to make sure that you always have a quick way to test the results of older versions versus a newer version.

The other is that people often need older versions of packages, such as if someone wants to use your package but they're using an older version of R on a server where the policies prevent an update to R. Perhaps a newer version of your package includes a new dependency which only works with a package that depends on a certain version of R or higher.

Of course, packages can always be installed without the compressed or binary files, but it's a nice convenience.

**2. Should I keep old package versions in a sub-folder of my GitHub R package directory?**

I would put it in a trunk or special subfolder that won't be automatically downloaded when someone tries to `install_github` or clone your master branch. Having a separate branch is a good idea.

**3. Should I save .zip files downloaded from GitHub as my old version, or produce a Source or Binary file during the package build itself (i.e. in RStudio)?**

As the package author you're in a position to know if these differ significantly and which if either is better, but by default I'd recommend the RStudio build because I assume (if you're like me) that you're less likely to include unnecessary files this way.

**4. Is this a superfluous activity if one isn't yet willing to publish to CRAN?!**

No, not necessarily. If people rely on your package then it really doesn't matter if it's on CRAN or not. In fact, not being on CRAN may be a reason to be more proactive like this to ensure that your users will always have access to the needed version of your package.